# React - How do I allow the user to upload and replace a file in an assets directory?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

I have a React application with a component like this:

```
export class UploadComponent extends React.Component {
    getFileInput(this: any) {
        this.refs.fileUploader.click();
    }

    onChangeFile(event: any) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        // What do I do here to replace a photo in my assets folder?
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    onChange={this.onChangeFile.bind(this)}
                    ref="fileUploader"
                    type="file"
                />
                <input
                    type="button"
                    value="Upload photo"
                    onClick={this.getFileInput.bind(this)}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In my `src` folder, I have a folder called `assets` with a file titled something like this: `photo.png`.  Throughout my application, I reference `photo.png` by name. I want to allow the user to upload a photo of their choice which will replace `photo.png` with the newly-uploaded photo and rename it to `photo.png` as well so that the photo will be replaced everywhere.

I don't necessarily want to have to store this into a database because that'll require getting it from the database. I was wondering if there is a solution that will just do it entirely in React.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: where are you going to store it when they refresh the page?

Comment: It will still be in the `assets` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform operations like `PUT`, `POST` etc you need some processing to happen on the "server/cloud" to accept the request and then to perform the action, in this case saving the file.

With that out of the way, there are multiple ways to approach the problem that you have described:

> (Please note that these solutions assume that you do not want to deal
>   with any servers like EC2. So I'm assuming that you will be using S3
>   to serve the react app. This is a cheap and relatively easy way to host a static app.)

1. **CloudFront**: You can configure cloudfront to act as a proxy for S3. Then you can simply issue a `PUT` request to the same prefix and upload the file. ([link 1](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/), [link 2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-content-uploads-post-put-other-methods/))
2. **API Gateway**: You can simply create a distribution wherein a endpoint accepts a request, routes the request to a `Lambda`
   function wherein you can perform operations like resizing,
   optimization etc and then save the file to S3 or where it is that
   you are hosting the app. Note the there is a limit on the payload
   size for API Gateway which is 10MB. ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html))
3. **Amplify - Client Side**: With this you can configure Amplify to have write access to the S3 bucket and use the storage module. ([link](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js))

The above options are in the **increasing order of complexity** in terms of setting them up and making sure the system is secure.

Answer (score 0):

> I reference photo.png by name. I want to allow the user to upload a
> photo of their choice which will replace photo.png with the
> newly-uploaded photo and rename it to photo.png as well so that the
> photo will be replaced everywhere.
>
> I don't necessarily want to have to store this into a database because
> that'll require getting it from the database.

If you are deploying serverless app you can use storage service like `AWS S3` or `Azure Blob Storage`.

With server app you could also take the option above or use filesystem api if it is supported and you have permission to it and it is persistent.